# how to set 'nr of results' to influence paging while not all results are fetched though ajax yet?

Tags: jquery, datatables

To populate a paginated [datatables](https://datatables.net/)-table, I do ajax-calls to a backend.

Based on paging (from,to) parameters this backend should only return 20 results at a time. However, there might be thousands of hits that satisfy the query.

How would I configure datatables to use the thousands (say 18200) results as leading and draw pagination buttons accordingly? I can't seem to find an api-call to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. There's special server-side options that need to be configured. More info [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) and [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)